# Can use web socket and web services on the same Server?

Tags: web-services, websocket

as I mentioned in the title, I'ld like to know if Web Socket and Web Service can run on the same Server together.

Comment: yes they can, by the way WebSocket is asynchronous...

Comment: Of course two different things can run on the same computer.  Have you encountered an actual problem?

Comment: I made the server with node.js, I'd like to know if in the "index.js" file I can put the web socket and the web service code together. Sorry but I'm a beginner with this kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I know your problem because I have just know this since a few hour ago.You need a main code webservice include handler websocket.

Example URL websocket connection: `ws://site.com:8080/ws`

you can create a handler method GET with uri `site.com:8080/ws` and take to function `websocketHandler`

And another Handle work normally